# Change WKInterfaceButton background image on tap

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, wkinterfacebutton

I'm trying to change the background image of a `WKInterfaceButton` in my storyboard when a tap occurs. Also, on calling the `setBackgroundImage` to change the image, `appendValue(1)` does not work.

```
class keyPadInterfaceController : WKInterfaceController{
    @IBOutlet weak var OneClicked: WKInterfaceButton!
        let whiteImage = UIImage(named:"keybutton1.png")
        let goldImage = UIImage(named:"keybutton2.png")

    @IBAction func OneTapped(sender:AnyObject) {
        OneClicked.setBackgroundImage(goldImage)
        appendValue(1) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out `setBackgroundImage:forState:` instead of `setBackgroundImage:`

Comment: @bgfriend0 that method does not exist with a `WKInterfaceButton`

Comment: @DanielStorm Gotcha, thanks for pointing that out. I didn't have time to check into the issue, hence why I posted a tip via comment instead of posting an answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access images using `setBackgroundImage` [you must pass them from the users iPhone first](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceButton_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceButton/setBackgroundImage:).

Alternatively, you can use `setBackgroundImageNamed`. As a result, [WatchKit checks your WatchKit app bundle first, followed by the device-side cache](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceButton_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceButton/setBackgroundImageNamed:).

```
OneClicked.setBackgroundImageNamed("keybutton2.png")
```

Comment: OneClicked.setBackgroundImageNamed("keybutton2.png") worked! Thanks!